# DLP data scan from bigquery table showing row_index as null

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I have scanned a Bigquery table from Google DLP Console. The scan results are saved back into a big query table. DLP has identified sensitive information, but the row_index is shown as null "location.content_locations.record_location.table_location.row_index", can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to your question ? Like table structure, what were you looking for etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We no longer populate row_index for bigquery as it's not meaningful since BQ is unordered. If you want to identify the row where the finding came from, I suggest using identifyingFields which lives in BigQueryOptions when you create your job.

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-job-triggers#job-identifying-fields